# Start or run a docker container with a command

Tags: docker

I have a docker container that I am running as follows-

```
docker run -d --name mycontainer -v workspace:/build aem/java-buildpack /bin/sh -c "$COMMAND"
```

The container exits after `$COMMAND` finishes executing.

What is want is a logic that starts the container if its an exited state and executes `$COMMAND` OR runs the container if it doesn't exist and executes `$COMMAND`.

Something like -

```
docker start mycontainer -c "$COMMAND" || docker run -d --name mycontainer -v workspace:/build aem/java-buildpack /bin/sh -c "$COMMAND"
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You want to reuse an old container? Why? You really shouldn't. Containers are intended to be ephemeral. In fact, I encourage you to use `--rm` to auto-delete the container when it exits.